# Lean styles manager- Rails SCSS to style guide gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, rubygems, sass

I work at a startup where our entire site changes week to week.  Most of what we do gets thrown out, so we build quickly.  This often makes the code base unwieldy and demands we spend a lot of time re-implementing things which have already been done- either by other team members on the current rewrite or on previous rewrites.  The place this is most obvious is the total lack of design that goes into CSS.

It's clear that we'd benefit from a style guide (something like [this example](http://www.thoughtballoon.co.uk/blog/2008/11/11/example-css-style-guide-unit-testing-for-css)), but keeping it up to date would be annoying, easy to forget, and a source of errors.

What I really want is the ability to automatically rebuild the style guide as part of the build process.  I imagine lots of people have this problem.

**Are there any gems that automatically document CSS?**

Comment: Relevant: others have tried and abandoned this project: http://cssdoc.net/  |  https://github.com/imedo/css_doc

Answer (score 1):

Startups frequently look for a technology solution but in many cases, such as this the answer is that you need to do the hard human work.

You have identified what needs to be done well with "annoying, easy to forget" and that hints at what is usually more important - communication amongst the team.  Do you have standards, guidelines, procedures, policies?  No time for them?  Well there are hard lessons that can avoided, you just have to look at the big picture.  At the end of the day are you building somethings that is a quality product or is it just a throwaway prototype?  That should help determine a lot of things.

Comment: Appreciate the push back.  As technologists aren't we looking for annoying human problems to develop better solutions for?  I think this is worth pursuing.